# Leaky roof in wooden boat!

Tags: boats, wooden

Recently, my partner purchased a narrow boat to live on in the London canals.

It is great! The only problem is that it has a fully wooden roof, and after the last week of heat, the wood seems to have moved and there have sprung some leaks.

What should I do? I have been aware of this sort of lifestyle for around 2 months and am a little at a loss of direction.

Maybe even if someone here knows where to point us to get good advice, that could be great too :)

Comment: I think this question will fit better at Home Improvement Stack Exchange, but wherever it belongs, it needs a lot more details. Maybe you can even add pictures.

Comment: @Willeke: Per [diy/on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), boats are off-topic on Home Improvement Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Brian, a roof is a roof, whether it is over land or water, but if that is the rules, it is the rules. Do you know a better place for this question? (It is not here.)

Comment: @Willeke: The woodworking SE is happy to talk about [water-protection](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-protection), so OP's question might be on topic there.  Mind you, you are correct that the current questions lacks sufficient detail to be a on topic on ANY SE site.

Comment: Perhaps [Canal World](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=canal+boat+wooden+roof+site:www.canalworld.net) is a route to explore.

Comment: For me, the question also lacks information about what was tried or investigated. Even though it might be costly, I'm quite sure that professional boatyards will be able to solve this problem.

Comment: Wood expands and shrinks based on humidity. If you put a wooden boat into water, it will leak for the first few days until the wood is soaked and expands. The same probably applies to the roof